# Doing remote call to azure server

Tags: remote-access, azure

I was trying to make remote call to my azure server, but could not reach out.

Also when I do ping on remote ip, `pings` are unsuccessful. Azure server has two IPs, `private` and `public` but both of them does not success when I try to call remotely.

```
gm_client = gearman.GearmanClient(['130.72.28.23:4730'])
#tried using both public and private IP of azure server
```

This was I am trying to request to my remote server. While doing it on remote system in my local networks, it works fine.

Is there any permission related issue for remote azure server?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the issue..? 
1. Are you able to connect or ping from your local machine?
2. From where are you trying to connect, which is failing.?

Comment: @serverstackqns: sorry for inconvenience, I updated the description

Comment: are you able to ping from local?? or telnet to that port?

Are you trying to connect to the same remotely from any other azure vm?

Comment: I could not ping, but login using ssh is fine. I am trying to connect my local system(no azure). I already said it

Comment: sorry, I didnt understand this:

gm_client = gearman.GearmanClient(['130.72.28.23:4730'])

What does this do..? What you need as output?

Comment: @serverstackqns: updated the code

Comment: I cant see any changes :( :(

Comment: : ( , `This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to open the port 4730 (and any other you possibly use) on your Azure VM.

Navigate to VM-> Endpoints tab -> Add

Azure only routes tcp and udp protocols, in that case, ping does not work since it uses ICMP protocol.

Don't forget to open internal OS firewall as well.